# php domDocument() saveHTML save only first image when HTML starts from <img>

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have following problem. When HTML starts from `<img>` tag and I save  `$dom->saveHTML()` I'm getting only first image as response. But when I add any string before `<img>` tag I'm getting extra `<p></p>` tag for HTML. Why is that?

```
$h = '<img src="https://example.com/one.jpg" alt=""><br><p>bla</p><img src="https://example.com/foo.jpg" alt=""><br>';

$h = 'abc<img src="https://example.com/one.jpg" alt=""><br><p>bla</p><img src="https://example.com/foo.jpg" alt=""><br>';
```

Above are examples inputs

```
<?php

$h = '<img src="https://example.com/one.jpg" alt=""><br><p>bla</p><img src="https://example.com/foo.jpg" alt=""><br>';

    echo'start<br />';
    echo htmlspecialchars($h);
    echo'<br />end<br />';

    $dom = new domDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($h, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $img_class =  $image->getAttribute('class');

        if($img_class == '') {
            $image->setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-rounded');
            echo'add class <br />';
        }
    }

    $my_post_content = $dom->saveHTML();

    echo'start<br />';
    echo htmlspecialchars($my_post_content);
    echo'<br />end<br />';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friend I have made some tests of your script and it seems the second image disappears because of the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` than you pass to `$dom->loadHTML($h, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

There could be a simple solution to do this "hack" and use something like this:

`$h = 'abc<img src="https://example.com/one.jpg" alt=""><br><p>bla</p><img src="https://example.com/foo.jpg" alt=""><br>';`

Then just manually cut the necessary things from the string but I give you a better solution:

```
$h = '<img src="https://example.com/one.jpg" alt=""><br><p>bla</p><img src="https://example.com/foo.jpg" alt=""><br>';

echo'start<br />';
echo htmlspecialchars($h);
echo'<br />end<br />';

// blank document is used because we want to extract only the
// html inside <body> from $dom 
$blank = new DOMDocument;

// initialize the $dom object and nothing is changed in this code
$dom = new domDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($h); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $img_class = $image->getAttribute('class');

    if ($img_class == '') {
        $image->setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-rounded');
        echo'add class <br />';
    }
}

// now get the body that will containg updated HTML 
// and insert all it's children in the blank document
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($body->childNodes as $child) {
    $blank->appendChild($blank->importNode($child, true));
}

$my_post_content = $blank->saveHTML($blank);

echo'start<br />';
echo htmlspecialchars($my_post_content);
echo'<br />end<br />';
exit;
```

and output will be:

```
start
<img src="https://example.com/one.jpg" alt=""><br><p>bla</p><img src="https://example.com/foo.jpg" alt=""><br>
end
add class
add class
start
<img src="https://example.com/one.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-rounded"><br><p>bla</p><img src="https://example.com/foo.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-rounded"><br>
end
```

as you see you have both of you images.

Cheers!